# Android - is there a function like onBackPressed() for the home button?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

i am looking to create a code for both the home and the back button. I understand how to use the onBackPressed() but i have no clue about using the home button. I have heard its not possible but cant i use @override

Answer (score 2):

You can never override Home button event listener. And there is no such method available for programmers. Google has not given privilege for doing so, to avoid malware obstruct the device.

Answer (score 1):

No there are no such things available. But you can use some activity callbacks such as onPause.. which gets called when you press home button.

Look at the below example run it and at logcat check for the method that gets called when you press home button and then write your code with that method which suits you.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("Destroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("Pause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("Resume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        System.out.println("Stop");
    }


}
```

Comment: I didn't understand.Do you mean at the output? what error do you get?

Comment: im not really sure what the problem was, so i restarted eclipse and then it worked fine. Thanks